# Write an SQL query using CTE's and window functions inside it to retrieve the top 5 customers along with their total order values across all orders

Tags: mysql

```
with customerCTE as(
select c.customerName, od.quantityOrdered,
sum(od.quantityOrdered*od.priceEach) over(partition by c.customerName) as totalOrderValue
from customers c inner join orders o on c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
inner join orderdetails od on o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber)
select * from customerCTE
order by customerName desc limit 5;
```

output:

```
customerName    totalOrderValue
Euro+ Shopping Channel  820689.54
Mini Gifts Distributors Ltd.    591827.34
Australian Collectors, Co.  180585.07
Muscle Machine Inc  177913.95
La Rochelle Gifts   158573.12
```

the above is the required output...but below is the my output
Output:

```
+-----------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| customerName                | quantityOrdered | totalOrderValue |
+-----------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| West Coast Collectables Co. |              46 |        43748.72 |
| West Coast Collectables Co. |              49 |        43748.72 |
| West Coast Collectables Co. |              33 |        43748.72 |
| West Coast Collectables Co. |              39 |        43748.72 |
| West Coast Collectables Co. |              46 |        43748.72 |
+-----------------------------+------------
```

Comment: What is preventing you from including `quantityOrdered` in your result?

Comment: Please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: Have you been told to use cte and window function or was that your decision?

Comment: You must GROUP BY in CTE and obtain customer name and total amount and total value, in outer query you'd limit this rowset. Window function not needed for this task until you need in all ties (if 5th and 6th have the same total value then you need in both to be returned - in this case you must use RANK() while ordering by the total value).

Answer (score -1):

WITH CustomerTotalOrder AS (
SELECT
customer_id,
SUM(order_value) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) AS total_order_value
FROM orders
)

SELECT
customer_id,
total_order_value
FROM (
SELECT
customer_id,
total_order_value,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_order_value DESC) AS ranking
FROM CustomerTotalOrder
) ranked_orders
WHERE ranking <= 5;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).